How can I prevent Tailscale from overwriting /etc/resolv.conf on Linux?
I'm using Tailscale on a Linux system, but I'm running into an issue with Tailscale's "Magic DNS" feature, which is overwriting my /etc/resolv.conf file and preventing server name resolution.
Here's my setup:
I have Tailscale installed in a directory where tailscale and tailscaled binaries are located.
I start the daemon using a shell script after each boot, which looks like this:
/data/tailscale/tailscaled -no-logs-no-support -statedir /data/tailscale/state

According to the documentation, Magic DNS can be disabled by running
tailscale up --accept-dns=false

which would prevent /etc/resolv.conf from being modified.
Since tailscaled is already starting up and enabling Magic DNS (without my explicitly running tailscale up), I’m not sure how to apply the --accept-dns=false setting before the daemon has a chance to modify /etc/resolv.conf.
Is there a way to configure Tailscale to disable Magic DNS from the start, or should I modify my startup script to include tailscale up right after starting tailscaled?
Any advice on the correct sequence or setup to prevent /etc/resolv.conf from being overwritten would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This seems to be an intended security feature to prevent DNS leaks. Are you sure that preventing tailscale from modifying it is the right solution?

Aren't the options given to --up persistent in Tailscale? Though I'm slightly tempted to suggest using systemd-resolved to get "best of both"...
